# apply merge to a list of data.frames

Tags: r, merge

I have a list of data.frames with just one column and a `character` value:

```
> list.df[c(1,5,8)]
$1
     X..1L..
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E
6      F
7      G
8      H

$5
   X..5L..
1    A
2    C
3    D
4    F
5    G

$8
   X..8L..
1   A
2   D
3   F
4   G
5   H
6   I
```

And another data.frame

```
> df
  V2  V5      V9
1  A  31 0.13029
2  B  80 0.29443
3  C 166 0.01354
4  D  11 0.39589
5  E  62 0.61794
6  F  40 0.35808
7  G  31 0.62581
8  H  54 0.24983
9  I  19 0.47199
10 J  97 0.26518
```

I would like to merge each data.frame in the list with `df`, I've tried creating a function 
   `func <- function(x,y){merge(x, y, by.x=x[,1], by.y=y[,1])}` and then applying it to the list but it does not work.

```
lapply(list.df, func, list.df, df)
```

I know that I can split `list.df` in several data.frames and then `merge` each of them individually, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it in the `list`

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two mistakes. One in your function and the other one in how you call your function:

```
func <- function(x,y){merge(x, y, by.x=names(x)[1], by.y=names(y)[1])}
lapply(list.df, func, df)
```

Comment: Hi again @eddi, when the list has 9,000 elements and the data.frame dimension is 17,000 rows by 1000 columns, is there any way to speed up the function `fun`? many thanks

Comment: use `data.table`s instead of `data.frame`s - a quick search on SO or google will get you started, something along the lines of `dt = data.table(df, key = 'V2')` and then using `fn = function(x){df[x]}; lapply(list.df, func)` is probably a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this helps but to merge the list perhaps try

```
df.list <- do.call(merge,list.df[c(1,5,8)])
```

but one thing I would note is that from the looks of it, your dataframe columns dont have names...have a go at naming the columns BEFORE merging, this should help...

```
colnames(df) <- c("col1","col2","col3")
```

Comment: Error in as.data.frame(x): argument "x" is missing, and when I add `df.list <- do.call(merge, list.df, df)` Error in if (quote) args <- apply(args, enquire)